# Using escape sequences with Terminal

Tags: terminal, serial-port, microcontroller, vt100

I am working with `Minicom Terminal (VT102)`. I have a micro-controller node which sends data to the minicom through serial (UART). I wrote some functions to work with terminal.

```
typedef unsigned char uchar_t;

uchar_t clear_cmd[] = {0x1B, '[', '2', 'J', '\0'};
uchar_t gotoxy_cmd[] = {0x1B, '[', 0, ';', 0, 'H', '\0'};

void clearTerminal()
{
    puts(clear_cmd); // puts() sends data serially to PC
}

void terminalWrite(uchar_t row, uchar_t col, const uchar_t *str)
{
    gotoxy_cmd[2] = row;
    gotoxy_cmd[4] = col;

    puts(gotoxy_cmd);
    puts(str);
}

void main()
{
    init_uart(); // Initialize UART

    clearTerminal();
    terminalWrite(2, 12, "Admin Login"); // 2nd line 12th column
    terminalWrite(4, 6, "Password: ");   // 4th line 6th column
    while(1);
}

[Assume all necessary header files are added]
```

I am getting output something like this
[image: Login Screen Minicom Terminal] Displayed on first line and not in the specified line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up the documentation for "gotoxy" command: You send the coordinates in ASCII:

```
printf("\x1B[%u;%uH", row, col);
```